# PHP batch file renaming

Tags: php, regex, file-rename

I have a bunch of files named like this...

```
full-file(1).jpg
full-file(10).jpg
full-file(11).jpg
full-file(12).jpg
full-file(2).jpg
etc...
```

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to rename all these files using PHP so that they get renamed like this...

```
full-file0001.jpg
full-file0010.jpg
full-file0011.jpg
full-file0012.jpg
full-file0002.jpg
```

I've got as far as reading all the files from a folder and looping through them but not sure about the best way to remove the brackets and make the number 4 digits with leading 0.

```
$image_files = get_files($thumbpath);
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: `full-file` can be any name or exact this one..?

Comment: full-file can be any name, it's just the brackets that need removing and the number that needs padding

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression to get the digit, and then zero-pad it using `sprintf()`:

```
$image_files = get_files($thumbpath);
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
  // Capture \d+ into $matches[1]
  preg_match('/\((\d+)\)/', $file, $matches);
  // Pad it with %04d in sprintf()
  $newfile = sprintf("full-file%04d.jpg", $matches[1]);
}
```

Example:

```
php > $file = 'full-file(12).jpg';
php > preg_match('/\((\d+)\)/', $file, $matches);
php > $newfile = sprintf("full-file%04d.jpg", $matches[1]);
php > echo $newfile;
// full-file0012.jpg
```

#### Update (for more flexible filenames):

To please the downvoter I can only assume wanted more flexible filenames, expand the regular expression:

```
$image_files = get_files($thumbpath);
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
  preg_match('/([^(]+)\((\d+)\)(.+)/', $file, $matches);
  $newfile = sprintf("%s%04d%s", $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);

  // And rename the file
  if (!rename($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "Could not rename $file.\n";
  }
  else echo "Successfully renamed $file to $newfile\n";
}
```

The pattern matches first, everything up to the the first `(` with `([^(]+)`, followed by the number via `(\d+)`, and everything remaining via `(.*)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Any chance of adding the code to actually do the file name rewrite?

Comment: @user736129 I added the `rename()` call above.

Comment: that's excellent. Thanks for you help. Just to let you know, I needed to make a couple of tweaks to get this to work. There's a typo in the snippet `$newfile and $newname` and I needed to prefix the filenames with the path. Apart from that, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mixture of REGEXP (remove brackets) and string padding (to force four digits).

Note I use a replacement callback to do both operations in one place.

```
$files = array(
    'full-file(1).jpg',
    'full-file(10).jpg',
    'full-file(11).jpg',
    'full-file(12).jpg',
    'full-file(2).jpg'
);

function pr_callback($match) {
    return str_pad($match[1], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
foreach($files as $file)
    echo preg_replace_callback('/\((\d+)\)/', pr_callback, $file).'<br />';
```

Outputs:

full-file0001.jpg
full-file0010.jpg
full-file0011.jpg
full-file0012.jpg
full-file0002.jpg

Comment: Doesn't SO log that sort of thing, to see who does it?

Comment: SO is able to automatically detect and undo abusive and serial downvoting (and upvoting), but this doesn't look like abuse, more someone being a troll.

Comment: The plot thickens. Someone just voted me back up, then down again. The downvote took off the +10 from the upvote, rather than merely deducting 2 like a normal downvote does. Weird...

Comment: Sounds actually more like an undone upvote (which removes 10) than a downvote which removes 2.  Here's a +1 since your answer was good before we learned that filenames had to be flexible

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen anyone recommend [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/sscanf) yet.

```
<?php

$files = array(
  "full-file(1).jpg",
  "full-file(10).jpg",
  "full-file(11).jpg",
  "full-file(12).jpg",
  "full-file(2).jpg",
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  $n = sscanf($file, "full-file(%d).jpg");
  printf("full-file%04d.jpg\n", $n[0]);
}
```

returns:

```
full-file0001.jpg
full-file0010.jpg
full-file0011.jpg
full-file0012.jpg
full-file0002.jpg
```

This only works if "full-file" is the actual name of your file, of course.  sscanf() is not a regex parser, it merely extracts data using printf()-style format strings ... though it does do some more advanced format recognition than is documented at http://php.net/sscanf .  If you need to handle other filenames, you can extend the format string:

```
<?php

$files = array(
  "this-file(1).jpg",
  "full-file(10).jpg",
  "foo(11).jpg",
  "blarg(12).jpg",
  "full-file(2).jpg",
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  $n = sscanf($file, "%[a-z-](%d).jpg");
  printf("%s%04d.jpg\n", $n[0], $n[1]);
}
```

returns:

```
this-file0001.jpg
full-file0010.jpg
foo0011.jpg
blarg0012.jpg
full-file0002.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need [str-pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php). A sample soon...

**EDIT 1**: solution using `str_pad` and `preg_replace_callback`.
**OBS**: Anonymous functions only in php5.3+.

```
foreach ($image_files as $file)
{
    $o = preg_replace_callback(
            "|\((\d+)\)|", function($matches)
            {
                $r = str_pad($matches[1], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                return $r;
            }
            , $file);

    echo $o . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files aren't actually called **full-file**(0000).**jpg**:

```
<?php 
$arr = array('full-file(1).jpg',
             'full-file(10).jpg',
             'full-file(11).png',
             'full-file(12).jpg',
             'full-file(2).gif',
             'abc(12345).jpg',
             'def(99).jpg',
             'xzy-file(100).jpg');

function format_filename($matches){
  return $matches[1].sprintf("%04d",$matches[3]).'.'.$matches[5];
}
function process_array(&$value){
    $value = preg_replace_callback('/^(.*?)(\()(\d+)(\)).(jpg|png|gif)/','format_filename',$value);
}

array_walk($arr,'process_array');

print_r($arr);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => full-file0001.jpg
    [1] => full-file0010.jpg
    [2] => full-file0011.png
    [3] => full-file0012.jpg
    [4] => full-file0002.gif
    [5] => abc12345.jpg
    [6] => def0099.jpg
    [7] => xzy-file0100.jpg
)
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Use code:*

```
preg_match('/^(.*?)\((\d+)\)(.*)$/', $name, $m);
$name = sprintf("%s%04d%s", $m[1], $m[2], $m[3]);
```

*See and test it [here](http://ideone.com/BA94q).*